# After Zookeeper audit is disable Stopped Working

Tags: apache-kafka, cmd, environment-variables, apache-zookeeper

**I wanted to install the Apache Kafka but stuck in installing the Zookeeper**

I extracted all the file and created the environment variables as well and now it stopped working after
"Zookeeper audit is disabled."

[image: Output after running the command "zkServer" to start Zookeeper]

Now after following through these links,

1. https://www.programmersought.com/article/22066571206/
2. https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.2/zookeeperAuditLogs.html

I updated both the files (skServer.cmd and conf/zoo.cfg). Adder a line "-Dzookeeper.audit.enable=true" in skServer.cmd file and "audit.enable=true" in conf/zoo.cfg.

Now the output has changed to "Zookeeper audit is Enabled." but still it doesn't do anything and stops there like before.

[Output after running the zkServer command with files edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPF6j.png)

Even tried changing one file at a time but the same output and still stops working.

Can anyone help me understand the problem and provide a solution as well?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Once i have seen such issue while doing configuration after enable just run kafka it will work. ignore this once enable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`zookeeper-server-start`  or `zkServer.cmd` do not return, by design. It's tailing the logs and waiting for a client connection

You must start a second terminal to run the Kafka broker, [as mentioned in the Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_startserver)

Answer (score 0):

Kill all java services. 
In Linux run `killall -9 java` 
Re re-run the zookeeper and Kafka server.
It works